# Where to create views for my Oracle APEX application

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a Oracle APEX application that runs using user/schema A and I want to access data that resides in schema/user B. Does it makes more sense to create these views in schema A or B ? Does the views should always reside in the same schema that owns the data ?

Answer (score 4):

You have various options.

What is crucial, is that user B should grant (at least) SELECT privilege to user A - otherwise, A can't access B's data.

If users reside in different databases, then it is not about *grants*; you'd have to create a database link between them (but I guess that's not the case here).

What next? Create a view! Where? Anywhere you want.

- if you create it in schema B, Apex application will have to reference it using owner's name. For example

  ```
  select * from b.some_view
  ```

  Another option is to create a synonym in schema A:

  ```
  create synonym some_view for b.some_view;
  ```

  Then you'd reference it as

  ```
  select * from some_view;
  ```
- if you create it in schema A, you'll have to reference B's tables by preceding table names with owner name, e.g.

  ```
  create view some_view as
    select e.employee_name, e.employee_id
    from b.employees e
  ```

  and, of course, use it as

  ```
  select * From some_View
  ```

---

What would be a better option? Can't tell; both approaches are OK, pick the one you like the most.